# Removing characters within a single string

Tags: php, html, xampp, notepad++

example:

```
  $name1="abcdefg";
  $name2="csawea";

Output: bdfgsw
```

i want to make a php code that removes all the same characters and its duplicate that is in Input1 and Input2, im new in PHP so im kinda confused in the codes, i know the strrpos,substr func but i need to see a finish product in order to understand the flow. TNX!!

other ex:

```
$name1= "aaabb";
$name2= "bccc";

Output: aaaccc
```

Comment: this isnt really the output of the game flames but dont finish code coz i want to finish it myself :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match();` or `str_replace();`.

Comment: tnx i added that str_replace coz its much more easier to use, im kinda confused on the preg_match..